# How to extract and ignore span in markup? - python

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

**How to extract and ignore span in HTML markup?**

My input looks like this:

```
<ul class="definitions">
<li><span>noun</span> the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or <a href="sale.html">sale</a> of the same <u slug="product">product</u>, as when a restaurant <a href="chain.html">chain</a> takes over a <a href="wine.html">wine</a> importer</li></ul>
```

Desired outputs:

```
label = 'noun' # String embedded between <span>...</span>
meaning = 'the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or sale of the same product, as when a restaurant chain takes over a wine importer' # the text without the string embedded within <span>...</span>
related_to = ['sale', 'chain', 'wine'] # String embedded between <a>...</a>
utag = ['product'] # String embedded between <u>...</u>
```

I've tried this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = '''<ul class="definitions">
...     <li><span>noun</span> the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or <a href="sale.html">sale</a> of the same <u slug="product">product</u>, as when a restaurant <a href="chain.html">chain</a> takes over a <a href="wine.html">wine</a> importer</li></ul>'''
>>> bsoup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> bsoup.text
u'\nnoun the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or sale of the same product, as when a restaurant chain takes over a wine importer'

# Getting the `label`
>>> label = bsoup.find('span')
>>> label
<span>noun</span>
>>> label = bsoup.find('span').text
>>> label
u'noun'

# Getting the text.
>>> bsoup.text.strip()
u'noun the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or sale of the same product, as when a restaurant chain takes over a wine importer'
>>> bsoup.text.strip
>>> definition = bsoup.text.strip() 
>>> definition = definition.partition(' ')[2] if definition.split()[0] == label else definition
>>> definition
u'the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or sale of the same product, as when a restaurant chain takes over a wine importer'

# Getting the related_to and utag
>>> related_to = [r.text for r in bsoup.find_all('a')]
>>> related_to
[u'sale', u'chain', u'wine']
>>> related_to = [r.text for r in bsoup.find_all('u')]
>>> related_to = [r.text for r in bsoup.find_all('a')]
>>> utag = [r.text for r in bsoup.find_all('u')]
>>> related_to
[u'sale', u'chain', u'wine']
>>> utag
[u'product']
```

Using BeautifulSoup is okay but it's a little verbose to get what's needed.

**Is there any other to achieve the same outputs?**

**Is there a regex way with some groups to catch the desired outputs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still has a pretty *well-formed structure* and you've stated the *set of rules* clearly. I would still approach it with `BeautifulSoup` applying the "Extract Method" refactoring method:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<ul class="definitions">
<li><span>noun</span> the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or <a href="sale.html">sale</a> of the same <u slug="product">product</u>, as when a restaurant <a href="chain.html">chain</a> takes over a <a href="wine.html">wine</a> importer</li></ul>
"""

def get_info(elm):
    label = elm.find("span")
    return {
        "label": label.text,
        "meaning": "".join(getattr(sibling, "text", sibling) for sibling in label.next_siblings).strip(),
        "related_to": [a.text for a in elm.find_all("a")],
        "utag": [u.text for u in elm.find_all("u")]
    }

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
pprint(get_info(soup.li))
```

Prints:

```
{'label': u'noun',
 'meaning': u'the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or sale of the same product, as when a restaurant chain takes over a wine importer',
 'related_to': [u'sale', u'chain', u'wine'],
 'utag': [u'product']}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PyQuery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) is another option to using BeautifulSoup.  It follows a jQuery like syntax for extracting info out of html.

Also, for regex...something like below can be used.

```
import re

text = """<ul class="definitions"><li><span>noun</span> the joining together of businesses which deal with different stages in the production or <a href="sale.html">sale</a> of the same <u slug="product">product</u>, as when a restaurant <a href="chain.html">chain</a> takes over a <a href="wine.html">wine</a> importer</li></ul>"""

match_pattern = re.compile(r"""
                (?P<label>(?<=<span>)\w+?(?=</span>)) # create the label \
                                                         item for groupdict()
                 """, re.VERBOSE)

match = match_pattern.search(text)
match.groupdict()
```

outputs:

`{'label': 'noun'}`

Using the above as a template, you can build on that with respect to the other html tags too.  It uses `(?P<name>...)` to name the matched pattern (i.e. label) and then a `(?=...)` *lookahead assersion* and a *positive lookbehind assertion* to perform the match.

Also, look in to [findall](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.regex.findall) or [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.regex.finditer) if you have a doc that has more than once instance of your mentioned text pattern.